# SSL証明書の発行先と、実際のURLが異なる場合、不都合はありますか？

Tags: centos, ssl, letsencrypt

Let’s Encrypt で、SSL証明書を取得しました。

---

**試したこと**

```
$ sudo certbot --nginx
Which names would you like to activate HTTPS for?
```

と聞かれたので、

```
6,9,10
```

と入力したら、無事https化出来たのですが、3つのSSL証明書の発行先は全て同じです。

- a.example.com のSSL証明書発行先は、a.example.com
- b.example.com のSSL証明書発行先も、a.example.com
- c.example.com のSSL証明書発行先も、a.example.com

b.example.com と c.example.com は、URLと SSL証明書発行先　が異なるのですが、このままでも問題ないですか？

$ sudo certbot --nginx　からやり直して、6,9,10と入力するのではなく、それぞれ1件づつ入力することを3回繰り返した方が良いですか？

---

**環境**
・CentOS7
・Nginx
・Let’s Encrypt
・certbot

Comment: 異なるサイトの証明書を導入したとしても「とりあえず暗号化できた」という自己満足感は得られます。現実にはHTTPと何ら変わりないですが、それに対する不都合の有無はご本人にしか判断できないと思います。

Comment: 「現実にはHTTPと何ら変わりない」。ブラウザで「https://」表示されているのですが、実際には「http://」という意味ですか？　それとも例えブラウザで「https://」表示されていたとしても本来の証明書の役割を果たしていない、という意味ですか？

Comment: なぜSSL証明書を取得しhttpsで提供しようとするのかを理解しないと、sayuriさんのコメントの意味が分からないと思います。いっそhttpでいいのでは、と思いますね。